# Convert HTML to crystal report

Tags: javascript, html, crystal-reports

i am getting Ajax response as JSON which retrieves data from database, what I'm trying to achieve is to use the JSON data to populate the crystal report file which I have already created with pictures and all. Can I achieve this by just using HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you take care of converting the JSON to a file format (e.g. CSV) or data source (Excel, ODBC, ...) that Crystal can use.  JSON is not a valid data source for Crystal Reports.